# Remove/Override RabbitMq TopologyRecoveryException logs in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

As per the RabbitMq java client API, https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#recovery

> Unhandled exceptions related to connection, channel, recovery and
>   consumer lifecycle are delegated to the exception handler. Exception
>   handler is any object that implements the ExceptionHandler interface.
>   By default, an instance of DefaultExceptionHandler is used. It prints
>   exception details to the standard output.
>
> It is possible to override the handler using
>   ConnectionFactory#setExceptionHandler. It will be used for all
>   connections created by the factory:

we have

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
cf.setExceptionHandler(customHandler);
```

What is the same implementation for .NET RabbitMq client? Adding this code is still writing console logs and not executing my logic and How do I remove the existing event handler?

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
connection.CallbackException += (x, y) => {
   Console.WriteLine("Handled"); // not printing
};
```

I would like to override/remove the logs which are printing to console because of topologyrecoveryexception.

[image]

Could anyone help me on how to override this default behavior of logs to console by RabbitMq.Client using v4.1. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should upgrade to the latest `5.X` .NET client.

Then, notice in the `ChangeLog` file that console logging was replaced by event source ([link](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/master/ChangeLog.md#replace-consolewriteline-logging-with-eventsource)).

`CallbackException` is used when one of your callbacks raises an exception, I believe. It has nothing to do with exceptions generated by the library.